# colorbox form submit and get post data from the form

Tags: javascript, forms, submit, colorbox

Ive been doing this for quiet sometime and i cannot get my luck

1. on main page im calling the form with

   a class="viewForm" name="viewForm" href="viewForm.php">Select date

with javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".viewForm").colorbox();
    });
</script>
```

this one is working

1. Now the viewForm has this code

   #### SELECT DATE

   From
       
       to

with java script

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
function lightbox(){    
  $.colorbox({width:"80%", height:"80%", iframe:true, href:"select-date.php"});
}
</script>
```

this is also working.

1. The problem is when im clicking the submit button i think the post data from and to where not pass on the select-date.php. Please i need help on this.

Comment: What do you get in select-date.php.Have you checked print_r($_POST);

Comment: supposed to be i should get it here is my code on the php <?php

if(isset($_post['submit'])) {
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password');
 if (!$con)
  {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  $result = mysql_select_db('db_inventory', $con);
  mysql_query($result);

 $from=$_post['from'];
 $to=$_post['to']; 
 
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT date, name, quantity FROM inventory WHERE date >= '" . $from . "' AND date <= '" . $to . "' ORDER by id DESC");

}
?>

Comment: this is working outside colorbox, but when im calling the outside html inside colorbox i get error mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given